Using an IF statement in Power BI
I have a really simple equation in Excel, where I choose the measurement unit for the length of wire I want, and it converts every value to mm.
How would I do something similar in Power BI, where I can choose the measurement unit (eg mm, inch, m etc) and then manually input the value to give a result in mm to use at a later stage.
Thanks
DF
The IF statement works fine in Excel, but I cannot find the way to do it in PBI

Update/Edit the question above with your Excel IF formula so we can have a better idea of what you are aiming for.

Thanks for the reply :). The statement is “=if(O3=M, N325.4,(if(O3=N, N31000, etc”

usually you can change Q3 to column name. if that does not work, pls provide some sample data and expected output.

I did something similar using the power query side and created a simple table with the unit and a multiplier column and then merged it to my dataset. The standard unit I wanted had a multiplier of 1. I used this to display the units as is but provide a slicer filter with the bin ranges I needed.

To write If statement in your PowerBI column , you can Create a new measure and then write your conditions in that measure and you are ready to go.
second thing is , you can duplicate the column and use filters in that using IF conditions.
